# Time complexetiy for searching a list in a HashSet

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, time-complexity, hashset

Let's say I have a HashSet that stores lists

```
HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> hs = new HashSet<>();
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();

a.add(1);
a.add(2);

b.add(3);
b.add(4);

c.add(5);
c.add(6);

hs.add(a);
hs.add(b);
hs.add(c);


ArrayList<Integer> d = new ArrayList<>();

d.add(3);
d.add(4);

hs.contains(d); // what is the time complexity of this operation?
```

Now if I were to perform a search on this HashSet, would the time complexity be O(1) or O(n) or O(n*m) where 'n' is the number of Lists and 'm' is the number of elements in each list?

I'm preparing for interviews for FAANG and this question came up in one of the mock interview questions. I would appreciate anyone who can help me find an answer to this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a nasty one. As the [documentation for `HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) states, the actual operation is `O(1)`. Problem here is that we have to calculate the hash of a `List`, and the [API of `List::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#hashCode()) shows a loop, so `O(n)`. Likewise, even if the hash would be `O(1)` we have to compare the "found" list with the input list since hash collisions are a thing. And comparing two `List`s is `O(n)`.

Comment: @xerx593 `O(n*m)` is an extreme case if all hashes collide, but yeah, it could (in theory) happen. What I do not understand is your statement of `O(1)`. Hash calculation and list comparison is always `O(n)`.

Comment: @xerx593 can you link the exact reference? I somehow fail to find it.

Comment: I found (only) on the quick: https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/AbstractList-source.html , @Turing85 ..like any good/generated equals method it starts with `if(this==o) return true;`

Comment: @xerx593 aaaaaah okay. Yeah true. For this special case (`b` being the same exact object in the list`), yeah, equals comparison is `O(1)`. Got your point.

Comment: @xerx593 well, we have still to calculate the hash code of the input-list. And since the hash does not seem to be cached, we are back to `O(m)` best case scenario.

Comment: Yuk! Let's make them hash functions faster! ;(;(

Comment: Thank you xerx593 and Turing85 for the thoughtful responses. This is very helpful! To conclude, it will take O(m) operations to perform the contains function as it takes linear time to generate the hash code. Let me know if this is in line with what has been discussed so far.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's **discouraged** to use hash-based Collections with mutable objects.

`HashSet` implementation uses a `HashMap` under the hood. When a new entry is being added into the under-laying map, it creates a `Node`. Node has the following declaration:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next;

    // ...
}
```

The field `hash` is marked as `final` it would be calculated **only once**. While examining nodes (for instance, during invocation of `contains()`, `add()`, etc.) the value stored in the `hash` would be used, the hash would **not** be recalculated. That's why it is not advisable to store mutable objects in a `HashSet`, or as a `HashMap`s key.

The time complexity of the `contains()` check on a `HashSet` if nodes are relatively evenly distributed between buckets would be **O(1)**. In the worst case scenario, when all the nodes end up in the same bucket, `contains()` would run in **O(log n)** (because nodes after a curtain threshold would be arranged into a Tree, and prior to Java 8 it would be **O(n)**).

And in this case, `contains(myList)` would have a time complexity of **O(m)**, where `m` is the size of `myList`, because each element in the `myList` needs to be examined in order to calculate the hash (note that the hash of the list provided argument as an argument would be computed only once per `contains()` call).

In case if the contents of `myList` would **not** be `Integer`, but an object with a badly implemented `hashCode()` contract, which creates a lot of collisions, the time complexity of the `contains(myList)` would be **O(log n + m)** (where `n` is the number of nodes in the set) because computing the hash of the argument would cost **O(m)**, and traversal of the nodes arranged into would runt in **O(log n)**.

Comment: While the implementation might guarantee `O(log n)` worst-case time complexity, this is not guaranteed by the class contract. So a conservative estimation would be to estimate an `O(n)` instead of `O(log n)` worst case complexity. But that's a nit-pick :)

Comment: @Turing85 Prior to Java 8 it indeed would **O(n)** in the worst case, when nodes would form a one huge Linked List.

Comment: The O(log n) case requires either, having different hash codes (for a bucket collision) or comparable elements (for an actual hash collision). Since `ArrayList` does not implement `Comparable` and true hash collisions are possible, the worst case still is O(n).

Comment: By the way, it doesn’t require “a badly implemented hashCode()” to trigger the worst case. Just create an `ArrayList` and add as many `-30`s you like. Makes ~2³¹ lists with the same hash code.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Alexander Ivanchenko. This helps me understand under the hood operations of the hash set.